# Expanded widget not working as expected inside Columns and Rows

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Note.**
this is just an example to simplify what I want to achieve.

I want to fill this space with a yellow container:

[image: Before adding the container]

So I made a container and wrap it with `Expanded` widget to fill the whole space and this is what I got:

[image: the wrong output shape]

the code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
  decoration:
      BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.black)),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            color: Colors.blue,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('300x300')),
          Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.green,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text('100x100')),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(width: 100, color: Colors.amber),
            )
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

what I want to achieve is something like this:
[image: expected shape]

the code of this shape:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
      decoration:
      BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.black)),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            color: Colors.blue,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text('300x300')),
          Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                color: Colors.green,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('100x100')),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('100x200')),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

If I know the heights and widths so yes I can design this shape.
but, what If I don't know the height of the blue Container?

I think it's a problem with `Expanded` that should be fixed.

`Expanded` widget should expand its child to the limit boundary of its parent, not expanding its parent too!!

**Edited.**

I will explain my actual problem to anyone who didn't understand my problem:
[image]

I have this list of comments and what I want is that green line beside the comment fills the height to the end of the comment widget.

so I can't set a fixed size to the comment because I may have a comment with a long string so the line won't fill to the end of the comment text would exceed its limits.

Comment: the ```Expanded``` depends on its parent.. but in your case your parent doesn't have a height. Try wrapping your ```Row``` or ```Column``` (depends were you use it) with Container and add a height.

Comment: `Expanded` is already expanding its child to the limit boundary of its parent. This is not a bug, The only widget providing constraints to `Expanded` is the `Scaffold`, therefore it expands to the height constraint provided by the `Scaffold`. If you want this widget to size itself the way you expect, you need to be providing a height constraint that encompasses both of the `Column`s.

Comment: @Reign
I already know that, and at the beginning of my question, I said it's just an example of what I want to achieve.
I am asking this question because I am stuck in a situation that I want the expanded take the full height of Its parent which is already inside a row and I am not able to design 
I just use this example to simplify my question.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore
I can provide some images of my actual problem if you want to.

Comment: @AbdelazeemKuratem You misunderstood the documentation. Your row will fill its parent height. Then the children of row, will expand depends on the parent height. So in the end, you'll have your expanded view expand troughout the whole screen height

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, yes I understand that but I think it's better if Expanded widget expands to it parent, not to the Scaffold,
or if we have another widget that doing the same action 
I hope you get it know

Comment: @ChristopherMoore
please check my edit again

Comment: @ChristopherMoore can you explain your point, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I could solve it by using the `IntrinsicHeight` widget.

I just wrap my `Container` with it and then the `Expanded` widget works as expected.

**the final UI:**

[image: the final output]

**Here is the code:**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Container(
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.black)),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text('300x300')),
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      width: 100,
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.green,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text('100x100')),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(width: 100, color: Colors.amber),
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the BLUE container has no fixed height.  This is not a solution.  If you did indeed solve the problem with variable height comments, please share.

Comment: @Dave My case was the BLUE container has height and the problem was with the yellow one

Comment: That's odd.  Looking at the actual output screenshot, compared with your box mockup, there's no way you could know the height of the comment box.

So our designs are the same.  I fixed this with Table, TableRow amd TableCell widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Try once

```
new Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                    height: 200,
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Container(
                              //width: 100,
                              //height: 300,
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              alignment: Alignment.center,
                              child: Text('300x300')),
                        ),
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 2,
                              child: Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  // height: 100,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text('100x100')),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 4,
                              child: Container(
                                  width: 100,
                                  //height: 200,
                                  color: Colors.amber,
                                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                                  child: Text('100x200')),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your row in a `Container` with fixed height so your `Expanded` won't fill the parent height (in this case is `Scaffold`)

EDIT:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 300,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                color: Colors.blue,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('300x300')),
            Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text('100x100')),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(width: 100, color: Colors.amber),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: So what if I don't know the height of parent, what should I do then?

Comment: If you're trying to achieve the `300 x width`, you can make a container that have fixed `300` height and width using `MediaQuery`. the container's child should be filled with your code above

Comment: Please, check my edit
and thanks for your response.

Comment: Obviously there's no problem with the `Expanded`. You just have to wrap your child view to a parent. What you meant the parent is your `Row` but it's not. Your `Row` will act like parent but actually `Row` itself will fill it's parent height which is `Scaffold` so your `Expanded` will fill `Scaffold` height

Comment: I swear, I know If I put it inside a container that has fixed width and height it will work but my situation is different, I don't know the height of the parent

Comment: Please post the actual code you're using. I think the dummy code you're using is not relevant to the situation.

Comment: that's why I made this example to make the people understand the problem.
just think of it as my first image, 
the blue box=> is the comment content,
the green box => is the profile picture,
the yellow box => is the line that I want to draw,
so if the comment has a long text that can take 10 or 20 lines then the blue box will be too long and I won't be able to determine the height of the parent
hope you get it

Comment: Your `Column` will expand with it's child. Your `Row` height will expand to your column height. You should use the `Column` with 2 child in it contain profile picture and `Expanded` so you'll have the full line fill to your first `Column` height

Comment: you still don't get it, this comment(Row) is already inside a column that contains the comment and its replies and this column is already inside listview(for each comment)
so the height is infinity and if you used expanded it will expand its child and forcing its parent to expand because it doesn't have a fixed size, and here we go again the app is crashed because expanded height is infinity.

sorry, but I can't provide the main code because it is very complex and it's hard to combine them together into the same file

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code and modified it a bit. There is no issue with Expand but that may not be useful for you.

My edited code:

```
 class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: height,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5,
                height: height,
                color: Colors.blue,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text('300x300')),
            Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5,
                    height: height*0.5,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text('100x100')),
                Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.5,
                    height: height*0.5,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Text('Remaining'))
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My output
[image]

If you see the code, I've nowhere hard-coded the width or height. I'm using [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) to fetch the screen size and width.

```
var height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.5;
```

This line is important to define the height of the row. The children will automatically adjust to the specified height.

Now, you can play around with the height and width of your choice. Here is my other output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this self contained example worked for me, feel free to adjust paddings and margins etc for your needs:

[image]

#### Rough code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 16),
      child: Table(
        columnWidths: const {
          0: FixedColumnWidth(40), // Width of avatar
          1: FixedColumnWidth(16), // padding
          2: FlexColumnWidth(1), // white box
        },
        children: [
          TableRow(
            children: [
              TableCell(
                verticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.fill,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    // NOTE: Added empty column needed to fix render bug
                    // with Expanded in release build only.
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: 20,
                              bottom: 8,
                              top: 48,
                            ),
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            width: 2,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: const [
                            CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                              radius: 20,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const TableCell(child: SizedBox.shrink()),
              TableCell(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 0, 0, 12),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                            16,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: const [
                            Text(
                                "This is some comment text that goes onto several lines and may be great or may be not!"),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```